# How do I get the UI to render with my state with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component, react-class-based-component

I have an onClick method to react that changes the state of a property named pointer. The function works on a functional level however the UI does not update with my state unless I double click the button (onClick method). I tried turning the component to a class component to utilize the render method but still no results.

```
let questions = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "This person tends to be quiet"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "This person is compassionate and has a soft heart."
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "This person is disorganized.."
  }
]
export default class Quiz extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      pointer: 0,
      currentAnswer: ""
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
<div>
<h1> {questions[this.state.pointer].title}</h1>
<button onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                      this.setState({
                        pointer: this.pointer++
                      });
                      console.log(this.pointer);
                      this.forceUpdate();
                    }}>
</div>
)
}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some code here, where is the so called click handler? Where are the components connected? Where do you use `setState` or `useState`?

Comment: Its updated now my fault I forgot to look over the code.

Comment: `this.pointer` or `this.state.pointer`? Why `this.forceUpdate()`, Why (although not required) don't you use a class function to at least separate the code from the rendering a bit? (I'll pick `id: 3` here :D )

Comment: State must be inmutable and this.pointer++ is a mutable action, instead, you should write this.state.pointer + 1

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I needed to put "this.state.pointer + 1" not " this.pointer++ ".Thanks, icepickle

Answer (score 0):

You just write it, but at least I will give you an explanation.

Every action on State must be performed in a inmutable manner, basically that means that when you call a setState function, the operation provided to setState must return a new value instead of altering the state directly.

Please take this into account for later operations as it will introduce horrendous side effects on your application.

[you can read about it here.](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/why-react-and-redux-need-immutable-data-dae3ab3611a0)